# MySQL only showing last data

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm trying to get the website read a table from my database but its only showing the last row of my table. this table is for test purposes to learn how to read out my database

what i'm trying to do is when a username is created the table will be updated and showed on the website.

searched stackoverflow for the correct answer but nothing works. What am i doing wrong?

here is my code:

```
  <body>

  <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username=""; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="test"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name

    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

    // check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }

    //select rows 
    $sql= 'SELECT id, username, country FROM members';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
   {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $f1 = $row['id'];
        $f2 = $row['username'];
        $f3 = $row['country'];
    }
   } else {
    echo "0 results";
   }

mysqli_close($conn);
?> 
    <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">id</font>
      </td>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">username</font>
      </td>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">country</font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
      </td>
       <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
      </td>
       <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
      </td>
    <td>
  </body>
```

Comment: Oh no! Not the `<font>` tag!

Comment: try using: <?php echo $row['id']; ?>

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know the <font> tag is "sort of"not done... but it was for simple test purposes trying to understand the main mindset behind it: display tables the right way. and showing them on a simple website. 
implemented it with bootstrap atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only output the last row.  You're reading every row here:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $f1 = $row['id'];
    $f2 = $row['username'];
    $f3 = $row['country'];
}
```

But you're reading them *into the same variables*.  So every time that loop iterates, you overwrite the previous values in those variables.  As a result, those variables will contain only the *last* row's data.

Put the *output* step into the loop as well.  Structurally, it would look something like this:

```
/* output HTML table header here */
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $f1 = $row['id'];
    $f2 = $row['username'];
    $f3 = $row['country'];
    /* output HTML table row here */
}
/* output HTML table footer here */
```

Comment: Ahh i see. Thanks for the quick reaction. It's working now.
spend hours trying to solve this but now i understand how its working. 
Keep this question as answered.

Comment: @MaikelHulst: Glad it's working!  If you wish to mark the question as answered, only you (as the asker) can do that.  This is accomplished by clicking the check mark next to the answer which resolved your question.  And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I did the check mark. thank you for welcoming me. Will help other people as soon as i am experienced enough.

Answer (score 1):

The following `while` loop will execute when the page loads. You are over-writing the variables `$f1`, `$f2`, `$f3` in each iteration and finally when the program comes out of the `while` loop, the values of each of these variable will be the `id`, `username` and the `country` of the last row of your query results array.

```
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $f1 = $row['id'];
    $f2 = $row['username'];
    $f3 = $row['country'];
}
```

What you should do is, adding the table data inside this while loop, like this

```
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $f1 = $row['id'];
    $f2 = $row['username'];
    $f3 = $row['country'];
 ?>

  <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
  </td>
   <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
  </td>
   <td>
    <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
  </td>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All of you `<TD>` and `Variables` like `$f1`, `$f2` and `$f3` must be in the while loop.

Try example

```
<body>

<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
{
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

//select rows 
$sql= 'SELECT id, username, country FROM members';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
?>

<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">id</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">username</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">country</font>
        </td>
    </tr>

<?php
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
    $f1 = $row['id'];
    $f2 = $row['username'];
    $f3 = $row['country'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
echo "</table>";
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?> 

</body>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You keep resetting the values of `$f1`,`$f2` and `$f3` in the while loop

Try this:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username=""; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="test"; // Database name
$tbl_name="members"; // Table name

$conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

// check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

//select rows 
$sql= 'SELECT id, username, country FROM members';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $Results = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $Results = array('f1' => $row['id'], 'f2' => $row['username'], 'f3' => $row['country']);
    }

    var_dump($Results);
} 
else {
echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A good answer will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

You need to output one table row per record, e.g. like so:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">

    <tr>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">id</font>
      </td>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">username</font>
      </td>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">country</font>
      </td>
    </tr>

<?php
   // output data of each row
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $f1 = $row['id'];
    $f2 = $row['username'];
    $f3 = $row['country'];

    ?> 

    <tr>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
      </td>
       <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
      </td>
       <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
      </td>
    </tr>

<?php

}
 mysqli_close($conn);

?>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
  <?php
    $host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username=""; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="test"; // Database name
    $tbl_name="members"; // Table name
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
    // check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
      trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    //select rows 
    $sql= 'SELECT id, username, country FROM members';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    ?>
    <table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">id</font>
      </td>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">username</font>
      </td>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">country</font>
      </td>
    </tr><?php
   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
   {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $f1 = $row['id'];
        $f2 = $row['username'];
        $f3 = $row['country'];
    ?>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f1; ?></font>
      </td>
       <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f2; ?></font>
      </td>
       <td>
        <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"><?php echo $f3; ?></font>
      </td>
    </tr>
     <?php    } else {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">NO Record Found</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
   }
   }
   mysqli_close($conn); ?> 
    </table>
  </body>
```